# How to add a class to parent element when there are several

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

as described in the title I would like to add a class to the parent element of one element if I have several of the parents.

To explain it in more detail what I mean, I'll give you a quick overview of the initial situation.

The markup:

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <span class="iconfont more"></span>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>some more text</p>
        <span class="iconfont close"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see I've created a div "box" with some content, a span and also another div "slide" with some content and a span too.

The CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -500px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 500 ease-in-out
}
```

Let's add a bit of styling. The divs now have a width, height and position plus the slide box has received a transition to make the hole thing smooth. You may already know where the journey will end.

So let's do it by bringing up a new player:

```
.box.slided .slide {
    top: 0;
}
```

For now the rest is pure routine. Add/remove the class .slided to .box by clicking the span. It works fantastic and everyone is happy except me. Because what if I have more of these boxes? Of course using IDs instead of classes to make them unique will solve this too. But what if I don't know how many of them I'll have? And that's exactly the point.

How can I add or remove the class .slided to exact this div.box that contains the span I'm clicking on?

Thanks for your help

Edit: code I've tried

```
$('div span').stop().click(function(event) {
    $('box').addClass('slided');
});
```

Comment: You should post some code u've tried, but I think you could use jQuery `parent()` like `$("span").on('click',function(){ $(this).parents('div.box:first').toggleClass('.slided'); });`

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgotten to tag jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` and `closest()` to traverse the DOM in a relative fashion:

```
$('.more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass('slid');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5yp7r1wg/1/)**

Note that I've added a negative z-index to your slider div to prevent it from covering the 'more' link, rendering it inaccessible. This is probably not a viable production solution.

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5yp7r1wg/2/) with the transition working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your closest parent that matches your selector like this:

```
$('div span').stop().click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('.box').addClass('slided');
});
```

This code will now find its `box` parent in the context of the `span` that was clicked.